# Help with analysis of a signal that generates high frequency

Tags: oscillator, electromagnetic, high-frequency

I am trying to understand this circuit:

- In circle 1: I don't know why we make two capacitor in noise circuit, we can't do just one?
- In circle 2: The tuned circuit consists of capacitor C1 and inductor L1. This tuned circuit will act as an oscillator with zero resistance. Why we do the capacity and the inductance with transistor Q1 and how we generate frequency because we have just DC voltage?

[image]

Comment: Can you link where you found this design? There are a few other fishy things, like the 102 pF capacitor on the input side, and the fact the NPN BJT is drawn as an upside-down PNP part.

Answer (score 2):

Those two parallel capacitors C2 and C3 aren't for frequency tuning, they're for antenna matching and possibly harmonic suppression.  Most likely the reason they didn't use a single 10pF cap is that at 700MHz the single cap would have been close to resonance; it seems odd that C1 at 15pF isn't a concern, but they may be different packages, which will affect the resonance profoundly.  It's also possible that it was split for redundancy, the capacitors are separated by a carefully calculated length of transmission line, or it's a commonly used value on the board and they wanted to avoid loading another reel on the pick&place machine.